# Why is there an Unnecessary Spacing between the logo and the division in my html page

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to remove that huge spacing between the logo and division

Here's my HTML code:

```html
<main class="site-main page-main">
    <center><img src="img/corelogo.png" alt="Post" height="180" width="180" style="position: relative; top: -210px;"></center>
    <center>
    <div style="font-family: Questrial; font-size:40px;">Government Files Download</div><br>
```

Photo of site

[image: Photo of site]

CSS of site

[image: CSS of site]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

In your css you are using properties for image to place it on the top this space is due to setting the top property in **minus**

```
position: relative;
top: -210px;
```

You want to place the logo at the top in the navigation bar so you should set this property to navigation

```
position: relative;
```

and for logo use this property

```
position: absolute;
```

then set the top and left properties which want to set and where yo want to adjust the logo